# Combine the results of two rest calls in Pentaho Data Ingegration (Spoon)

Tags: rest, pentaho-spoon

Among others a first REST call gives back a value, that is used as parameter for a subsequent call against another REST endpoint. Both calls work perfectly fine independently when used with static values. Now, how do I bring the result of the subsequent back into the the result of the first call to dump all data into a single text file - that is my challenge.

[image]